# How can revisions be added to a review in Crucible, which isn't indexed

Tags: svn, atlassian-crucible

Lately I've added a repo to Crucible and indexed it.
Now I edited and committed some files, but they are shown as 'Added'.

Is Crucible able to include SVN revision prior to the indexing of FishEye?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Crucible wont be able to automatically add revisions unless it indexes it. You can however do it in 2 different ways

1. Create a svn diff file and upload that file to Crucible.
2. Use Crucible to explicitly search and pick up a file from the tree. This sometimes(not always) picks up the file.
3. You can just go to the repo viewer and force start index before its scheduled time as well. That also helps